# How auto refresh Fullcalendar using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar library for calendar view,

```
   <div id="calendar">
      <?PHP
        include("Calendar.php");
      ?>
   </div>
```

i managed to connect my fullcalendar to sql db using source code I got from internet which is `Calendar.php`

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end, color FROM tbl_calendar ";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();
```

, but how can i auto refresh my calendar?. the following is my code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today'
            },  
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },
            events: [

            <?php foreach($events as $event): 

                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            ]
        });
```

i tried to use several functions such as

```
       `setInterval(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', "Fetch.php" )
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', "Fetch.php" )
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' )
        }, 1000);`
```

but it doesn't refresh calendar but the calendar is keep blinking.
any solutions?

Comment: At the moment you're setting a static events array, not an event source which can be dynamically updated. This is because you're writing out the events as an array into the Javascript which gets sent to the client. It can't be modified. Then, adding/removing an event source using interval (every 1 second!!) is very inefficient. Read this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ which shows how to do the client-side part properly.  Then you need a script to receive the ajax request which just returns the events as JSON, and does nothing else.

Comment: P.S. Since you're doing your workaround refresh every 1 second I suspect the event source doesn't even have time to update before you run the command again - you should watch your network tab to see how long it takes to return from Fetch.php, and then add on a bit more time for fullCalendar to process the result. Also you didn't show it, but does `Fetch.php` return valid event data in JSON format? If so, you can use it as the ajax script I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: thank you for the answer sir!. i'm just wondering what will be the code/content of that 'myfeed.php' from the website you refer.

Comment: it will contain the database code to fetch the events from the database (similar to what you have got in your example above, except it should filter by the start/end dates supplied by fullCalendar, which will be available as $_GET["start"] and $_GET["end"] respectively), and then you build the event array (just like you do now, except not injecting it directly into the calendar JS), but then at the end you should use `json_encode()` to convert the resulting data to JSON. Sorry I didn't explain that before, I thought it would be fairly obvious that myfeed.php would need to fetch event data.

Comment: you already have something called Fetch.php mentioned - does that not do this job for you already? Or something close to it, which you could modify?